# Exchange 2010 Email Going to Wrong Address

Tags: exchange

We have a public folder for our HR group.  Originally this folder had the email address hr@example.com and all email sent from outside the company went here.

It was then decided that the HR group weren't noticing when there were new emails so I created a distribution group from the Exchange 2010 console.  This distribution group included 2 users and the folder above. In order for this change to be transparent to outside entities, I changed the email address of the public folder to hrfolder@example.com and made the email address of the distribution group hr@example.com.

But, this doesn't seem to be working.  Emails sent from inside our company (via Outlook) to hr@example.com just go straight to the public folder and nowhere else:

```
EventId  Source   Sender                            Recipients                        MessageSubject
-------  ------   ------                            ----------                        --------------
RECEIVE  STORE... CKrohn@example.com              {HRFolder@example.com}          Testing
DELIVER  STORE... CKrohn@example.com              {HRFolder@example.com}          Testing
SUBMIT   STORE... CKrohn@example.com              {}                                Testing
```

Other than testing with the message tracking logs, I'm not sure how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  While the SMTP email addresses were correct, the X400 address for the folder still had S=HR instead of S=HRFolder while the distribution group had S=HR2 instead of S=HR.  Once I fixed that, everything worked.